# addSubview to UIScrollView doesn't Show?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have added a tableView to a UIScrollView in the following fashion

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,400,320,380) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = HEADER_HEIGHT;
    tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
    [self.scroll addSubview:tableView];
```

I don't know it's not showing up on screen, I have tried making backgroundColor of tableview as black, and it is showing but no tableview is shown also doing

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(tableView.frame));
```

gives correct value, I have added other UIButtons to the scrollview which are visible but UITableView on screen it is not visible?

Comment: How about the delegate methods. ?

Comment: Can you show your required delegate methods of UITableView? I am sure the problem is there.

Comment: @TapasPal here are my delegate methods

Comment: If you use a tool like Reveal, can you see your table view?

Comment: what is the height of your `UIScrollView`??

Comment: set your scrollview bounds to uitableview and check it shows or not

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,380) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = HEADER_HEIGHT;
    tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
    [self.scroll addSubview:tableView];
```

Comment: change your y position in tableview

Answer (score -1):

Is you **set scrollview's delegate?**......

like **self.scroll.delegate=self;**

i think it may work after this...